# Shutdown Remote Server at 3AM

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to shutdown/restart a remote server at 3AM using this script

```
shutdown /r /f /t $([int]([datetime]"03:00AM"-(Get-Date)).TotalSeconds)
```

But PS doesn't like it because it's going into the next day, if I run this instead it works:

```
shutdown /r /f /t $([int]([datetime]"11:59AM"-(Get-Date)).TotalSeconds)
```

I've looked around but can't figure out how to get this command to run at 3AM, anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if "3:00AM" is in the past, then add 1 day:

```
$threeAM = [datetime]"03:00AM"

if($threeAM -lt (Get-Date)){
  $threeAM = $threeAM.AddDays(1)
}

shutdown /r /f /t $([int]($threeAM - (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that makes sense but when I try to run that it just gives me all the options for the shutdown command!

Comment: Works perfect now, thank you Mathias and AbrahamZinala!